# How to call and use the spring REST POST API in my angular app which is returning string without body?

Tags: java, spring, http-post, angular8, spring-rest

I am trying to access the POST API from my spring app to angular but little bit confused how to  use and access the given API in my angular app.

Spring REST API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWelcomeMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getLoginWelcomeMessage() {
        return details.getLoginWelcomeMessage();
    }
```

The given API is fetching the welcome message details from my oracle DB and returning a string value. I am trying to access the given REST API in my angular code through services. I had define the post service as follows

```
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  welcomeMessageService(){
    const headers = {'content-type':'application/text'}
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/API/getWelcomeMessage",null,
    {'headers':headers});
  }

}
```

As the post method requires three arguments URL, Body and header. But in my case my spring REST API doesn't contain any body and returning a string. So, I had define the body as null and change the header type to text as it is JASON by default.

At last, I am trying to access the given service method by injecting it in my component as follows-

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  message:string;

  constructor(private loginService : LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loginService.welcomeMessageService().subscribe(
      response =>{
        console.log(response);
        this.message = response;
      }
    )
  }

}
```

But when I am trying to assign the response to the string I am getting the error that string cannot be assigned to the object. I am little bit confused why this error is occurring as I had also changed the header type to string while defining my service but still getting the error.

It can be a great help if anybody guide me regarding this as I am new to angular and little bit confused with integration part of API with angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `{ responseType: 'text' }` and also send an empty body not null

```
export class LoginService {

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  welcomeMessageService(){
    return this.http.put("http://localhost:8080/API/getWelcomeMessage",{},
    { responseType: 'text' });
  }

}
```

Maybe you have copied the function wrong but check also here

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getWelcomeMessage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String getLoginWelcomeMessage() {
        return details.getLoginWelcomeMessage();
    }
```

This is a Post method not a put that you are trying to call

As for cors error add the following to the backend just above `@Controller` or `@RestControler` whatever you have

```
@CrossOrigin(value = {"http://localhost:4200"}, methods = {GET,POST,PUT,DELETE})
```

Comment: Thank you @Boug, but I am getting CORS policy error when I am running my angular app. **origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource** Can you please help me out with this if you have any idea?

Comment: Thank you for quick response but methods argument is giving error

Comment: Prior I had tried with this **@CrossOrigin(origins="http:// localhost:4200")**

Comment: put this CrossOrigin with methods above @Controller instead of method

Comment: I had tried that too.. still getting the same issue

Comment: Thanks a ton your approach works for me :-) only mistake is that I had define put instead of post and my api type is post..

Comment: You made my day bro :-) I am so happy today. Thanks a lot again

Comment: Hello Boug, Can you please given some suggestion regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/q/66061111/11543918?