# How to define @RequestParams of spring POST API to Http post method of Angular?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, post, angular8, spring-rest

I have a REST API that is accepting two parameters that are username and password and giving the result as true or false on the basis of user input at front end. I am facing some issue in calling the REST API to my angular 8 code.

SPRING REST API

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Authentication(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password) {

}
```

I am trying to access the given API through my angular 8 app through services and defined the service as follows :

AuthLoginInfo.ts

```
export class AuthLoginInfo {
    username: string;
    password: string;
 
    constructor(username: string, password: string) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

```
checkLogin(userInfo : AuthLoginInfo){
     return this.http.post(`${API_URL}/APP/checkData/${userInfo.username}/
       ${userInfo.password}`,{},{responseType: 'text'})
  }
```

But when I am running my app I am not getting the params in proper format. Can anyone tell me how to define the request params in HTTP POST API ?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Is the url you are calling something like `api_url/APP/checkData/yourUsername/yourPassword` ?

Comment: No, I want this to be appeared as http://localhost:8080/APP/checkdata?password=abc&username=xyz

Comment: Then what you are doing is correct. Are you able to call the endpoint with postman?

Comment: Yes, I am able to call it through postman but when I am hitting the same to the Angular UI it is not appearing correct. It seems to me something like this : http://localhost:8080/APP/checkData/abc/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20xyz

Comment: I am getting 404 not found as the URL is not coming in proper format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you send them from the frontend, they are considered path parameters not query parameters. Configure your backend in the same way

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/checkData/{username}/{password}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String Authentication(@PathParam("username") String username, @PathParam("password") String password) {

}
```

In case that you want to work with your existing code and you don't want to change your backend, then you must adjust your frontend. As your backend is right now it expects query parameters in the url, so you need to send those in the frontend

```
checkLogin(userInfo : AuthLoginInfo){
     return this.http.post(`${API_URL}/APP/checkData?username=${userInfo.username}&
       password=${userInfo.password}`,{},{responseType: 'text'})
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, Boug for response. Can you suggest something on front end side ? How to access the @RequestParam on the front end side as I am using spring in the back end and fetching the query parameters.

Comment: On the frontend you don't access any RequestParam. You receive only a response which is a text. That is what you will receive and take care in the frontend

Comment: I mean to say that I am fetching the username and password from the DB. I had used @RequestParam as I am fetching the query parameters. The given data is not coming from the path URI.

Comment: Can you suggest how to use HttpParams with post method at UI side?

Comment: As you have your  this.http.post(`${API_URL}.... in your UI it should work

Comment: Can you please give me some tips how you deal with such problems? Your suggestions are really helpful :-)